# Span with percentage width

Tags: html, css-tables

Like in case of tables

```
TD WIDTH 25    TD WIDTH 75
```

this is what I want to achieve with DIV/SPAN. All I have:

```
  <span style="background-color: green; width: 25%; display: inline-block;">1</span>
  <span style="background-color: yellow; width: 75%; display: inline-block;">2</span><br />
  <span style="background-color: green; width: 25%; display: inline-block;">a</span>
  <span style="background-color: yellow; width: 75%; display: inline-block;">b</span><br />
```

but then puts span to new line. It works with fix (px) sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use float

```
  <span style="background-color: green; width: 25%; float:left;">1</span>
  <span style="background-color: yellow; width: 75%; float:right;">2</span><br />
  <span style="background-color: green; width: 25%; float:left;">a</span>
  <span style="background-color: yellow; width: 75%; float:right;">b</span><br />
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the whitespace between the two spans.

```
<span style="display:inline:block; width:25%">..</span>
<span style="display:inline:block; width:75%">..</span>
```

These have a space between them, so the whole thing won't fit in 100%; it's 100% plus the width of a space wide.
If you remove the newline between the two spans, it will work.

```
<span style="display:inline:block; width:25%">..</span><span etc...>
```

Comment: this itself solved that. But for 100% sure, I added the floating

Comment: IMHO, this is the correct answer to the problem the OP posted. Not that the accepted answer is inappropriate, but it's a hack around the problem. This answer nailed the issue.